# get_attached_file returns wrong path after changing media upload dir

Tags: uploads, media-library, paths

I've changed the default WordPress media upload dir (http://example.com/wp-content/uploads) to (http://example.com/uploads). Everything is OK and media files are uploading and showing correctly. But when I use `get_attached_file` function to get the path of the file (e.g. `http://example.com/uploads/hello.jpg`), it returns the wrong path ( in this case: `home/username/public_html/wp-content/uploads/hello.jpg`).
So when I call the `file_get_contents` with this path, I get `failed to open stream no such file or directory` error!
How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem :) Actually this is my friend's website. I don't have any idea how he changed the upload dir but I noticed that there is no `define( 'UPLOADS', ''.'uploads' );` in his `wp-config.php` file. I added it and it's now working perfectly. I hope this helps other people who will facing this problem.